# Is there "plain" kubernetes and best solution for an "air gap" environment?

Tags: kubernetes

I am a new DevOps engineer, and my company, that works exclusively in an "air gap" environment, wants to have some container orchestration solution.
I learned a bit of kubernetes (using their online tutorial and hands on minikube), and want to implement a solution for our network.

The questions are:

1. Is there a "plain" kubernetes I can deploy? In their "[Getting started](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/)" page, under "Production environment", they link to "[Kubernetes partners](https://kubernetes.io/partners/#conformance)" that list many kuberenetes products (Openshift, GKE, etc.). If I understood correctly, all of these products wrap kubernetes, but is there a plain kuberenetes I can deploy in my environment?
2. I can't find many articles of tutorials about deployment of a kubernetes solution in an air gap network? Are there good tutorials, or better kubernetes solutions for this situation? (I talked with a partner that deployed an Openshift in an air gap environment and he said it took months and was a totally pain in the ass, something that I prefer to avoid...).

Our network use VMware's ESXs and VSphere.

Thanks!
Aviv

Comment: Just for your own use, I think you are talking about an “air gap” network rather than “offline”

Comment: Thanks! I edited the post, hope it makes more sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

GKE and friends are hosted products so mostly not useful for you. Most on prem Kubernetes distros/installers support an airgap mode though you will likely need to manually copy over some container images to your local registry. Picking a distro is a much deeper question than will fit in a SO answer and in your case will probably involve a support contract anyway.

Also yes airgap networks are a compete pain and never worth the trouble so only do this if you can’t manage to overrule your Legal team.